# OpenGL translation glm right side or left side?

Tags: c++, opengl, translation, glm-math

Hello i am new to OpenGL and I need some help with this... Everywhere I found that to translate an object in 3D space, you should use the model matrix multiplied by the vertices. But if I do that, my program works weird (nothing translates). If I try vertices multiplied by the model matrix the translation works. Where is my problem?

```
// Wrong program nothing translate
(Cpp main)
glm::mat4 M;
M = glm::translate(M, glm::vec3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f));
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(M));

(Vertex shader)
in vec4 pos;
uniform mat4 mM; 
gl_Position =  mM*pos;
```

If in my vertex shader  I change this...it works

```
gl_Position =  pos*mM;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument of `glUniformMatrix4fv()` chooses if you want to transpose the matrix as part of uploading it. Since you use `GL_TRUE` for this value:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_TRUE, glm::value_ptr(M));
```

Your matrix will be transposed during the upload. Swapping the order of the operands for the matrix/vector translation to `pos * mM` compensates for the matrix being transposed.

If you want to stick to the much more common `mM * pos` order of multiplication, you simply have to use `GL_FALSE` for the argument, causing the matrix to be uploaded without being transposed in the process:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(M));
```